# jQuery change existing img alt tag

Tags: jquery, attr, alt

Simple question. I am trying to change all the image alt tags on my site using jQuery. The issue I'm having is that all my images have existing alt tags that I want to add to. Currently my code won't do anything, here is what I have placed just before closing the

```
<script>
$("img").attr({
alt: "This is some alt text"
});
</script>
```

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to add something to existing alt, or replace existing alt ? Cause I don't think a computer generated alt is of great use... alt are content, you should take care of it as other content.

Comment: "just before closing the..."? To much suspence, can't wait to know what you are closing!

Comment: ...apologies, just before closing the body

Comment: Is jquery loaded? any error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After jQuery 1.6 prop() is the correct one to use:

```
$("img").prop("alt", "This is some alt text");
```

http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
$(function() {
   $('img').attr('alt', 'Some Alt Text Here');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work, but you should use prop like this instead `$("img").prop('alt': 'This is some alt text');`.
You might be missing this inside you `<head>` tags to actually load jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

- Keep in mind that what you want will change alt to all images...

Comment: Even though it is true, that is not the problem, `.attr()` should work too.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, true. Thanks. I added that to my answer.